# Notify user when connection is lost

Tags: delphi, firedac, datasnap

An app I made connects to a database to retrieve and send data. Now, if the user has no Internet, it is the intention that the user is warned and sent to the start page.

If there is a solution for this on the service, the components are:

- DSServer
- DSServerClass
- DSTcpServerTransport

On the client-side, a connection is made with a `TFDConnection`.

I know there is a way to check the session if it is active or not, but I don't know how to put this in code.

Comment: You might like to look at this demo: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/Connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the demo of Dave Nottage, we managed to check if there is an internet connection.

Don't forget if you use it on android to add the .jar file in the library of the android
SDK.

[Klik here for the demo of Dave](http://%20github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/tree/master/Demos/Connectivity)